# How can I make a new df column that lists an index of a group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Not sure how to put this into words, but how can I make a new DataFrame column like `Subject`? I just need `Subject` to be like an index for each `Group`.

| Scores | Group | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4.85 | malware | 1 |
| 0.61 | malware | 2 |
| 2.47 | malware | 3 |
| 6.49 | other reuse | 1 |
| 6.21 | other reuse | 2 |
| 0.52 | other reuse | 3 |
| 0.49 | other reuse | 4 |
| 1.09 | other reuse | 5 |
| 1.71 | inoperable | 1 |
| 0.90 | inoperable | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to assign indexes to each "Group". You can use `groupby` + `cumcount`:

```
df['Subject'] = df.groupby('Group').cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
   Scores        Group  Subject
0    4.85      malware        1
1    0.61      malware        2
2    2.47      malware        3
3    6.49  other reuse        1
4    6.21  other reuse        2
5    0.52  other reuse        3
6    0.49  other reuse        4
7    1.09  other reuse        5
8    1.71   inoperable        1
9    0.90   inoperable        2
```